# MySQL return exact error/warning that stored procedure throws

Tags: mysql, exception

This is my first time with Mysql SP. I've a procedure that does several DML operations like inserts and updates. But it sometimes throws a warning. I want to show that exact warning as it is(on shell/console) when the script is executed. Currently, I get something like below when an exception occurs.

```
Query OK, 0 rows affected, 1 warning (0.08 sec)
```

When I execute the same procedure using a mysql client like workbench and execute the procedure. I get a proper error message. This is what I want printed on console.

```
1   10:33:03    call dbscripts(@param)  0 row(s) affected, 1 warning(s): 1062 Duplicate entry '124' for key 'PRIMARY'
```

How can I do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `SHOW WARNINGS`. From the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/show-warnings.html):

> `SHOW WARNINGS` shows information about the conditions (errors,
>   warnings, and notes) that resulted from the last statement in the
>   current session that generated messages.

Comment: how can i get the SHOW WARNINGS output table in QT / c++application